# none of options selected in show hidden files in folder option

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

I want to show my hidden files in one folder but when I go to folder options and view and select the "show hidden files" option, and after OK there is no effect in my folders. Stranger is that when I go to folder options again none of options is selected as shown in this snapshot:

[image: http://upload7.ir/imgs/2014-07/32388543887151073589.png]

Comment: run procmon in background and look for failed registry operations: http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-4-Process-Monitor

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you are logged in as administrator. If the problem still persists, try overriding the setting in the registry:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\explorer\Advanced\Folder\Hidden

rebooting machine after changing settings in registry may be necessary.

Comment: I try your answer, but no changes made.